Generating continuous signal using inverse short-time Fourier transform
I am trying to produce a discrete time domain signal, starting from a randomly generated spectrum components with fixed power spectral density (mainly very low frequency contents).
My first attempt was based on a sort of inverse short-time Fourier transform (ISTFT). Basically, I get my $M$-size random block of data representing my signal in the frequency domain, and than I apply the M-IDFT block-per-block.
The problem is that when I serialize the obtained vectors I (obviously) see signal discontinuities in correspondence of the block changes.
In order to solve the problem I tried to use an overlap of 50% plus a Hann window, but I obtain exactly the same result.
Any help please?

You first need to define precisely what constitutes discontinuous. Second, you will have to introduce some type of constraint that prevents it. Third, are the STFT samples for a continuous time-domain signal so independent that you can just choose M random values on a block-by-block basis?
